# profiling linux application with perf record

Tags: c++, linux, performance, perf

I've been trying to profile my C++ application in Linux by following [this article on perf record](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2011/07/profile-applications-linux-perf-tools.html). My understanding is all I need to do is run `perf record program [program_options]`, where `program` is the program executable and `[program options]` are the arguments I want to pass to the program. However, when I try to profile my application like this:

`perf record ./csvJsonTransducer -enable-AVX-deletion test.csv testout.json`

`perf` returns almost immediately with a report. It takes nearly 30 seconds to run`./csvJsonTransducer -enable-AVX-deletion test.csv testout.json` without perf, though, and I want `perf` to monitor my program for the entirety of its execution, not return immediately. Why is `perf` returning so quickly? How can I make it take the entire run of my program into account?

Answer (score 0):

Your commands seems ok. Try change the paranoid level at `/proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid`. Setting this parameter to -1  (as root) should solve permission issues:

```
echo "-1" > /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid
```

You can also try to set the event that you want to monitor with `perf record`. The default event is `cycles` (if supported). Check `man perf-list`.

Try the command:

```
perf record -e cycles ./csvJsonTransducer -enable-AVX-deletion test.csv testout.json
```

to force the monitoring of cycles.